# Share multiple api gateway in one serverless compose service

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-api-gateway, serverless-architecture

I have a project with serverless framework compose following this architecture

```
/services
    --- infra
    --- service-a
    --- service-b
```

The 'infra' service create and share two api-gateway (a private and public one), but in each service a can use only one. In each service a have a public lambda for creating an object (public api) and a lambda to approuve the object by an admin (private api).

I need this specific pattern cause it's a medical project.
How I can do select an api gateway for each lambda ?

Comment: possibly create multiple serverless.yaml files and use sls deploy --config infra-service.yml, sls deploy --config service-a-service.yml commands to deploy. You may have some code repetition but lambdas and most of the config code can be shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no "good" way to do it if you need to have two different APIGWs in the same Serverless service. The best approach would be to separate it into more services, e.g. `service-a-public`, `service-a-private`, and so on.

If you really need to use a single service that uses two separate APIGWs, then you need to write the integration as raw CloudFormation.